# Create combined index for JSONB column in PostgreSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, indexing, jsonb

I need to set a combined index on two fields from a JSONB in my PostgreSQL DB. I can set an index for a single field like so (using ActiveRecord in my Rails 6 application):

```
add_index :my_table,
  "(content->'reference')",
  using: :gin,
  name: 'index_my_table_on_content_reference'
```

This one works as expected. However, when I try to set a combined index for two fields, I get the following error:

```
add_index :my_table, 
  ["(content->'reference')", "(content->'ext_id')"], 
  using: :gin,
  name: 'index_my_table_on_content_ref_and_ext_id'
```

> ```
> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR: column "(content->'reference')" does not exist
> ```

What am I doing wrong and how can I create a combined index for multiple fields in a JSONB column?

And before you ask: Yes, each JSONB blob has a key named `reference`.

Using: Ruby 2.6.5, Rails 6.0, PostgreSQL 11

Comment: PG gives this error when the entire expression is escaped and treated like a column name. ```create index my_table_json_idx on my_table using gin((content->'reference'), "(content->'ext_id')");```. Seems there is problem with ActiveRecord escaping when it isn't desirable.

Comment: @Jindra Thx for your feedback. So your suggestion would be to write the migration in plain SQL?

Comment: I do not know Ruby On Rails or your ActiveRecord library so I can't really help you there. Maybe there is a way to tell it to not escape. If there isn't then plain SQL.

Comment: @Jindra I ended up using plain SQL. If you want please post your suggestion as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error `PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR: column "(content->'reference')" does not exist` means it's treating `"(content->'reference')"` as a column name.

Reproducing from SQL:

```sql
create index my_table_json_idx on my_table using gin(
   (content->'reference'),
   "(content->'ext_id')"
);
```

Note the quotes around the second expression.

It seems there is a problem with your ActiveRecord library and it is escaping your jsonb expression when it isn't desirable.

Either use plain SQL or try to make your ActiveRecord library not escape your expression.

After some Googling I think changing the array to string `"(content->'reference'), (content->'ext_id')"` might work.

Answer (score 0):

Ya Rails doesn't know how to dump your jsonb index using ruby. So SQL would be the way to go. This was a pretty good article for me when I started messing with jsonb [Rails & jsonb](https://nandovieira.com/using-postgresql-and-jsonb-with-ruby-on-rails)

```
def change
  reversible do |dir|
    dir.up do 
      execute <<-SQL
       CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idx_my_table_on_content_references on my_table using gin ((content->>'reference'));
      SQL
    end

    dir.down {execute "DROP INDEX IF EXISTS idx_my_table_on_content_references;"}
  end
end
```

Comment: This doesn't create a combined index, but I still see what you are getting at. Thx.

Comment: You may be able to create the clustered index the same way you do with regular columns. `((content->>'reference'), (content->>'ext_id'))`